# Cannot start deluged service (init.d)

Tags: 16.04, bittorrent, init.d, deluge

I installed `deluge`, `deluged` and `deluge-console`. All of them work fine and I can start the deluged daemon using this command

```
$ deluged
```

but I cannot start it using the `init.d` script that comes with it. Neither of these work:

```
$ sudo service deluged start
$ sudo /etc/init.d/deluged start
```

and if I check the status, it says `active (exited)`. This worked without any issues on my previous laptop running ubuntu 14.04, but doesn't on my fresh 16.04 installation.

I've tried everything I could think of; tail logs (they're empty), change permissions and mask (didn't do anything), change auth settings - but it just doesn't start. I've been at this for over an hour, and any help would be highly appreciated. Installing a torrent-client shouldn't take this long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so I got it working! I've been closely going over the `/etc/init.d/deluged` apparently the daemon mode of `deluged` **is disabled by default** (*WTF deluge, what else is the point of installing a daemon*) and you're supposed to **enable it manually** (*they also forgot to mention this in the user guides*).

Anyways, to enable it, open `/etc/default/deluged` in your favorite editor:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/default/deluged
```

and change `ENABLE_DELUGED=0` to `ENABLE_DELUGED=1`

Comment: I have the same symptoms, but already had ENABLE_DELUGED=1 ... No go.

Answer (score 1):

As explained on the [Deluge Service wiki](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/Service) you should be using `systemd` with Ubuntu 16.04.

> Most Linux distributions now use systemd. See ​wikipedia for releases
>   with systemd as default.
>
> ```
> systemd 
>
> Upstart (Ubuntu 11.04 to 14.10) 
>
> init.d (Obsolete)
> ```

The init script is provided by the Ubuntu package maintainers but the `/etc/default/deluged` file is mentioned in the [init wiki](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/Service/DebianUbuntuInitd)...

Comment: I like `init.d` more. And the init script in the wiki is very different than what comes pre-packaged with `deluged`.

Comment: it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

After adding 'VERBOSE=yes' to /etc/default/deluged, I got the warning message:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/deluged start
[....] Starting deluged (via systemctl): deluged.serviceWarning: deluged.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
. ok
```

And after running `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` the daemon was indeed running.

Note that my `/etc/default/deluged` now looks like this:

```
# Defaults for deluged initscript
# sourced by /etc/init.d/deluged

# change to 1 to enable daemon
ENABLE_DELUGED=1

# Added by carlo. Run the daemon as user 'deluge' instead of 'debian-deluged'.
DAEMON_ARGS="-d -c /var/lib/deluge/.config/deluge -l /var/log/deluge/daemon.log -L info"
USER=deluge
```

The reason I need the daemon to run as user 'deluge' is because the client runs as user 'deluge' and they share the same config directory. That is, the 'auth' file in both need to be the same, and for the rest it is TOTALLY unclear which files are used by the daemon and which are used by the client :/. I tried hard to get it to work using two different users but in the end BOTH also need read/write access to where ever the torrents are put, the data is downloaded to etc. In the end I ended up adding both users to eachothers groups and then using chmod g+s on all directories in the torrent/data tree, which makes the two users so equivalent that it didn't make any sense anymore to have two different users in the first place AND it STILL didn't work (all my torrents where in 'Error' state). So, I gave up and just went back to using a single user for deluge.