# Install new service daemon

Tags: 16.04, services

I managed to cobble this together before, but I've forgotten how and not sure that I did it correctly, but I know that Ubuntu switched from upstart to systemd with version 15 and I want to install a new service on my production server.

I have copied the scripts to init.d, but don't know how to proceed on the new system. I've tried googling several things, but keep finding upstart stuff. The one thing I found about systemd doesn't seem to cover installing a new custom script.

Comment: What in your question is not covered by http://askubuntu.com/q/833549/43344, http://askubuntu.com/q/835285/43344, http://askubuntu.com/q/825858/43344, http://askubuntu.com/q/707473/43344, and the many other questions on AskUbuntu that cover this topic?